# SUM query of a UNION ALL off by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sum, union-all

I have a query in which a table is created and left joined with a a `WITH name AS()` That portion of the query runs just fine and returns results as expected in the following format:

```
VISIT_ID | ACTUAL WEIGHT | STATED WEIGHT | WAS WEIGHT INFO OBTAINED?
123      | 1             | 0             | 0
321      | 0             | 0             | 1
567      | 0             | 1             | 0
...
```

I then use add a `UNION ALL` to it to obtain totals at the bottom of the columns. The columns `ACTUAL WEIGHT` and `STATED WEIGHT` are adding up just fine but the `WAS WEIGHT INFO OBTAINED?` column is off by 1.

The columns are flags 1 and 0, the third column will produce a 1 if both columns `[ACTUAL WEIGHT] AND [STATED WEIGHT]` are both `NULL`

Here is my query:

```
-- VARIABLE DECLARATION AND INITIALIZATION
DECLARE @SD DATE;
DECLARE @ED DATE;
SET @SD = '2013-12-16'
SET @ED = '2013-12-16';

-- THIS CREATES A TABLE WHERE ALL THE DESIRED VISIT ID NUMBERS WILL GO
-- THIS TABLE IS A UNIQUE CLUSTER
CREATE TABLE #T1
  (
  VISIT_ID VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE CLUSTERED
  )

-- WHAT GETS INSERTED INTO #T1. IT IS QUICKER TO USE #T1 THAN @T1
INSERT INTO #T1
SELECT DISTINCT PTNO_NUM

FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V

WHERE Adm_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
AND Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I'
AND PtNo_Num < '20000000'

OPTION(RECOMPILE);
--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++//

WITH WT AS
       (SELECT EPISODE_NO,
            MAX(CASE
                    WHEN FORM_USAGE = 'Admission'
                    AND OBSV_CD = 'A_WEIGHTOBTAINED'
                    AND DSPLY_VAL = 'Actual'
                    THEN 1
                END) AS [ACTUAL WEIGHT],
            MAX(CASE
                    WHEN FORM_USAGE = 'ADMISSION'
                    AND OBSV_CD = 'A_WEIGHTOBTAINED'
                    AND DSPLY_VAL = 'STATED'
                    THEN 1
                END) AS [STATED WEIGHT]

        FROM smsmir.obsv

        WHERE form_usage = 'ADMISSION'

        GROUP BY episode_no
        )

SELECT T1.VISIT_ID
, ISNULL(WT.[ACTUAL WEIGHT], 0) AS [ACTUAL WEIGHT]
, ISNULL(WT.[STATED WEIGHT], 0) AS [STATED WEIGHT]
, CASE
    WHEN [ACTUAL WEIGHT] IS NULL AND [STATED WEIGHT] IS NULL
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS [WAS WEIGHT INFO OBTAINED?]

FROM #T1 T1
LEFT JOIN WT WT
ON T1.VISIT_ID = WT.episode_no

UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTALS'
, SUM(WT.[ACTUAL WEIGHT])
, SUM(WT.[STATED WEIGHT])
, SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN [ACTUAL WEIGHT] IS NULL AND [STATED WEIGHT] IS NULL
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)

FROM #T1 T1
JOIN WT WT
ON T1.VISIT_ID = WT.[episode_no]

DROP TABLE #T1
```

Any info on why this is happening would be great.

I would like the info to all come out meaning I am trying to obtain the following:

```
VISIT_ID | ACTUAL WEIGHT | STATED WEIGHT | WAS WEIGHT INFO OBTAINED?
123      | 1             | 0             | 0
321      | 0             | 0             | 1
567      | 0             | 1             | 0
...
TOTALS   | 10            | 25            | 9
```

Comment: What number do you expect to see at the bottom of the last column (based on your sample data) and why?

Comment: based upon the sample data obtained, I expect to see an 11 at the bottom of the last column, instead I see a 10, this data covers exactly 1 day. I expected to see 11 because that is in fact how many 1's were in the column.

Comment: OK. Another discrepancy: your *main* code uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, while *total* code uses more restrictive `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Your "TOTAL* row can be implemented in the same query with [`ROLLUP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx) - no need for `UNION`.

Comment: trying that right now

Comment: I'll have to play around more with the `ROLLUP` as it looks like it could save me some time, but if you want, the problem for the code was by not using the `LEFT JOIN` in the `UNION ALL` query, so if you want to put that as the answer I'll accept it when I can.

Comment: Resurrected my response with the different answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discrepancy in your *row* code vs your *total* code.

The former uses `OUTER LEFT JOIN`, while the latter - **more restrictive** `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: i'll fix the question to reflect that, however the code is working as i expect after manual inspection of results, except the third column being off by 1 for the totals line

Comment: post updated

The columns are flags 1 and 0, the third column will produce a 1 if both columns [ACTUAL WEIGHT] AND [STATED WEIGHT] are both NULL